Is Tail Call Optimization intentionally not used for `vector<T> foo() { return bar(); }`, given `vector<T> bar();`?
Given:
int foo();

int bar() {
    return foo();
}

I expect bar to employ Tail Call Optimization (TCO), and that's what I see happens with the three major compilers.
However, it doesn't happen for any of those compilers when I change the code to the following:
std::vector<int> foo();

std::vector<int> bar() {
    return foo();
}

This latter, to me, looks like a tiny variation, and I don't see why TCO could not be used.
Complete example.

I would speculate it's because the allocations + deallocations are "visible side effects"

None of the compilers shown seem to realize the return value from baz is the same. Apparently all they care about is enforcing that the hidden first argument is returned but don't trust the called function to do that.

Maybe it could break RVO? bar() has to use RVO, but compiler doesn't know anything about foo and whether it employs RVO or not, so it has to play it safe?

Happens with every non-trivial type, tbh, with side effects in constructor\destructor.

You left out the icc compiler which does not have a problem optimizing it :)

Funnily enough clang does place a tailcall annotation on the LLVM IR,
but the backend seems to have other ideas... ( https://godbolt.org/z/535dxezqd ).

For people unfamiliar with the ABI, the calling convention says a pointer to the memory reserved for the return value must be passed in as a hidden first argument and that must also be returned. The unoptimized code saves and returns this pointer (hence no tailcall) while the optimized version realizes the very same pointer is returned by the called function anyway so tailcall can be used.

@Jester: This looks like a duplicate, but my test cases there with a struct of three 64-bit members doesn't TCO with ICC compiling as C or C++ (https://godbolt.org/z/dx1fs87nz), while this does with std::vector (which differs in not being trivially-copyable).  I suspect it's still GCC bug https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=91515 which has already been reported, though.

This looks like a missed optimisation opportunity, rather than something that is deliberately done. It takes significant development effort to implement optimisation steps in a compiler, and it is not always easy to identify ALL the cases (obscure edge cases or not) for which some optimisation can be applied. So the most likely reason that some cases gets well optimised and some (apparently similar) cases don't is that the people designing/coding the compiler anticipated one case but not the other, and there hasn't been enough justification (say, bug reports) to justify revisiting.
